# Node js listen on server rather then local?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, localhost

I've just started looking at node.js so forgive if i'm wrong.

I'm creating a basic chat application using this tutorial with socket.io - [Link](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

I've set it up and its running on local host but how can i get this to work so it would connect to my website address http:// mywebite.co.uk on a port

so http:// mywebite.co.uk/:101

Any ideas sorry if this is a basic question ?

This is my code

```
var express = require('express'),

app = express(),

server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

 server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Just run the app on your server?

Comment: Is localhost the same computer as mywebite.co.uk? Does your code bind it to listen on a specific network interface?

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: If your website is hosted on your local machine where your app is running you should do some portforwarding to open up 101 port, if your website is running somewhere remote you should run your app in the same location. Initialising this would be specific to your website hosting provider.

Comment: Edit: I'm trying to get it to run on my server which is live, i've copied the files over but its not working ? I'm using cpanel

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the way WebSockets work. In your server, you should have server side code for handling WebSockets events, for example you should listen first to the `connection` event and then to a specific even that you emit on the client side when you send the message. Conclusion: you need to distinguish between client and server side code for WebSockets. You need both...

Comment: If you website is already online, then your users just need to access it, and you will provide a chat (client side code). In this chat, you will emit a certain specific event, which is then capture on the server side...